# Unable to load MathJax dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mathjax

I have a ajax post request, which dynamically loads some math content like below

```
// post comment
    $post_comment.on("click", "[data-submit='post-comment']", function() {
        $.ajax({

            success: function(response) {
                if(response.success) {
                    $('#comment-list').load(' ' + '#comment-list');
                    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub, "comment-list"]);

                }
            },

        });
   });
```

The mathjax command above mentioned is unable to render the math script loaded dynamically.
While when I execute the same command on command-line, its working!!

It would be nice if someone explains why this is happening and how to fix

Comment: This looks like a case of [not waiting for an asynchronous event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: look at the callback of `load` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `load()` method uses ajax which executes asynchronously meaning after the request is sent to the server the statements after that will continue executing without waiting for the response from server comes back.

In this case when the `load` request is sent, before `#comment-list` is populated with the response the `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub, "comment-list"]);` statement will get executed, thus it is not rendering anything.

The solution is to use a callback provided by load to run the statements which has to work on elements loaded by the ajax request

Ex

```
$('#comment-list').load(' ' + '#comment-list', function(){
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub, "comment-list"]);
});
```